# Been wanting to get a tattoo saying, forgive but never forget in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, motto

so I'm currently looking for what's the best way to tattoo "forgive but never forget" but I know the direct translation in Google may not always be correct, hence I am seeking for help. The tone may be abit sentimental and more towards heartbreaking? Or rather anger and anguish as well.

Comment: Don't get tattoos in languages you don't understand, especially based on free advice from strangers. If what you want on your skin is 'forgive but never forget', just get that.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Although it's [improved some](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16768/how-good-is-the-new-version-of-google-translate), It's wise to [not trust Google Translate](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4349/what-is-google-translate-good-for).

Comment: @dbmag9 I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with getting something tattooed in a language you don't know as long as you get help from someone who does. I would also make an exception with Latin because in English (which the poster clearly knows) we have so many words of Latin origin. The chances of misunderstanding are not as high as with other languages.

Comment: @dbmag9 Not really a helpful comment. I could imagine any number of reasons, e.g. not wanting to write a special sentiment in the language of everyday speech, or liking the mystery that it's a meaningful inscription, but most people won't be able to read it, or loving the nimbus of a language that's 26 centuries old, or whatever. Personally, I don't understand why people get tattoos at all, but it's not really my business, is it?